# cakphp 2.0 file browser/uploader with CKEditor

Tags: php, cakephp, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in my cakePHP 2.0 application. I have installed it in my app/webroot/js/ckeditor directory.

ckeditor is showing image upload option and also configured these lines in `config.js`

```
 config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/app/webroot/ckeditor/pictures/';
 config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/app/webroot/ckeditor/pictures/';
```

Now, the image upload interface looks fine, but when i click on "Send it to the server" button, image doesn't upload to `folder path`?

Note :what is the next step to upload images to the folder?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you must link them to your uploder

like this

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = BASE_URL + 'filebrowser/browse.php?type=files';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = BASE_URL + 'filebrowser/browse.php?type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = BASE_URL + 'filebrowser/browse.php?type=flash';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = BASE_URL + 'filebrowser/upload.php?type=files';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = BASE_URL + 'filebrowser/upload.php?type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = BASE_URL + 'filebrowser/upload.php?type=flash';
```

Comment: Prefer putting the code directly inside your answer rather than in a picture. If you really need to use a picture, embed it.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on upload to server, Ckeditor send FileData at your server. You have to handle your $_FILES data at your server to given path, like @Ahmed Ebead mentioned. I use this in Yii2 like this :

```
  public function actionPublicUploadDrag(){
    return self::publicUpload(1);
}

public function actionPublicUploadBrowse(){
    /*prd(Yii::$app->request->get());*/
    return self::publicUpload(2);
}

// to provide browse facility
public function actionImageuploader(){
    //render your image browser page in this.
    exit;
}

private static function publicUpload($by = 1 ){

    $image = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('upload');
    $destination = "@backend/web/img/public_image/";
    if($image){
        $images = Image::getImagine()->open($image->tempName);
        //saving original
        $imageName = time().$image->name;
       $saved = $image->saveAs(Yii::getAlias($destination). $imageName);
       if($saved){
        //{"fileName":"590860cae9734.jpg","uploaded":1,"url":"\/userfiles\/files\/Public%20Folder\/590860cae9734.jpg"}
            $uploadPath = \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['img/public_image/'],true);
        if($by == 1){
            return Json::encode(["fileName"=>$imageName,"uploaded"=>1,"url" => $uploadPath.'/'.$imageName]);
        }else if($by == 2 ){
            return "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction('1', '$uploadPath/".$imageName."', 'Uploaded');</script>";
            }
       }
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: `<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction('1', '$uploadPath/".$imageName."', 'Uploaded');</script>` this code make my days. Thanks